# How to organize application's interaction with its graphical interface without user intervention?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm writing checkers for android. And I faced a problem with organization human vs computer part of program architecture. It's known that the user interacts with the program through the GUI. GUI elements have listeners which are responsible for some events.

So, when it is human's move, we can use those listeners to do all what needed. But, when it is computer's move, we can't use listeners because there is no directly interaction with the GUI.

My question is: where is in program structure I can manage neccessary operations and, most importantly, subsequent interaction with the GUI to manage computer's move?

And can I use Service for this?
Documentation said:

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user..

So, Servise is more useful for background processes. But for my case, i think it's not suitable..
Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for that.

Each time a player (IA or human) do an action (for example move), you post a custom event with all informations you need to the EventBus.

In your GUI, that you've registered to the eventBus, you get the event and display what you want.